# Spring hateoas polymorphic collections json

Tags: json, spring, collections

I'm having some troubles serializing polymorphic collections with spring hateoas.

After setting all the mappings in the POJOs I can serialize single resources correctly, but when it comes to collections I cannot do it. From what I've seen, when dealing with collections we have to set the type reference we're dealing with, but when it comes to Spring that stuff is done internally. I could override the ObjectMapper to deal with this, but it doesn't seem a good idea... What have you people been doing to solve this issue? And again, this only happens with collections not with single resources so it's not a problem of annotation configuration on the POJOs.

Any thoughts?